# NHibernate: Insert and update dates

Tags: nhibernate, updatedate

Using NHibernate, what is the best way to handle InsertDate (a.k.a CreateDate) and UpdateDate columns?

For example:

```
public class Customer 
{
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
     public virtual DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

There are probably multiple ways that this could be handle, but could someone who has done this before provide me with some advice.

If it's not obvious, I want InsertDate to be set to the date that a record was inserted and after that to be immutable. UpdateDate needs to be changed every time a record is updated.

Bonus marks if you answer using Fluent Nhibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use auditing interceptors for this. A good example can be found [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/27/creating-a-timestamp-interceptor-in-nhibernate.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I've used something similar to [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx).

Not so important - just to be complete - my version used Interceptors, not listeners. For more infos to interceptors and listeners read [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867341/nhibernate-difference-interceptor-and-listener).