# Fluent Nhibernate - Generate a non-primary-key sequence generated value

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity mapping quite similar to this one.

```
public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Code);

        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there's any possible way to have the Code field (which is not part of the Primary Key) autogenerated by a sequence. There's a GeneratedBy property, but it's only an IdentityPart class member.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how using Listeners makes it any easier to use a built-in method for using sequence generators for non-ID columns.

However, if the only solution is to hook into OnPreInsert, making a direct query to the DB & invoke the sequence and get its value, then I suppose I'll have to live with it.

Is this how you solved the issue, Mauro?

**Edit:**
posted the question on the nHibernate & FluentNHibernate google groups:
https://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/35d37b9abf3566f0
https://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/35d37b9abf3566f0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SaveOrUpdateEventListeners`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551701/how-do-i-implement-changetime-and-changeuser-columns-using-nhibernate) to see Jake's reply for how to get it working for Fluent.